# Nginx url configuration

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Can't get configuration working for nginx on url rewrites.

I have:

```
example.com/post.php?slug=example
```

I want it to be:

```
example.com/nyheder/slug
```

For htaccess it's easy for me to get it to work.

```
RewriteRule ^/?nyheder/(.*?)/?$ /post.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

In Nginx I have tried several ways:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /post.php {
        rewrite ^/?nyheder/(.*?)/?$ /post.php?slug=$1 last;
    }
```

Anybody that can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule needs to be moved into the `location /` or in the parent `server` directive.

Try a location directive like:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/nyheder/(.*)$ /post.php?slug=$1 break;

  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: With this one, it downloads the file instead. http://139.162.165.252/nyheder/the-cyber-house-rules